# Short story about a demon's demon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to identify a short story about a man haunted by a demon from another dimension that, I think, he calls "twisty" because it appears in his peripheral vision as a spinning twist of dust that moves along the skirting board of his room.  Eventually he befriends the demon who, it turns out, is escaping from its own demon haunting it from yet another dimension ...

I would estimate published in 1970s/1980s in English US/UK